# Google+ Share Button isn't work

Tags: button, share, google-plus, google-plus-one

I'm doing a website where I have a Share button for Google+. I'm trying it in my localhost server and when I click the button, it turns red with an advice. In the advice I read these motives of error:

- Server timeout: Check your Internet connection and try refreshing the
  page.
- Suspended profile: If your profile has been suspended, you
  won't be able to +1 content.
- Apps user: If your administrator hasn't
  enabled Google+ for your domain, you won't be able to sign up for a
  Google+ account to use the +1 button.
- Blocked cookies: If you've
  disabled 3rd party cookies in your browser you won't be able to use
  the +1 button.
- Logged out: If you've logged out of your account, you
  won't be able to use the +1 button.

I checked the different motives and I don't know how I can check the Apps user...

Answer (score 4):

This is expected behavior. Google has to be able to crawl your site to generate the preview snippet for the share. Google cannot crawl your localhost server.

To share pages, the content must be publicly accessible.

Comment: I'm using the plugin Share This for WP and I can share in Twitter and FB without problems :/